# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Contract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)

Tags: solidity, ganache, truffle-deployment

The client side application always throws the above error. I have connected the ganache account(by copying the private key)also with the correct port number in Metamask extension as well as in the truffle-config.js file but the error seems consistent.

```
    App={
    contracts:{},
    loading:false,

    load: async() => {
        await App.loadWeb3();
        await App.loadAccount();
        await App.loadContract();
        await App.render();
        // await App.renderTask();

    },
    // https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8

    loadWeb3: async () => {
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
          App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider
          web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
        } else {
          window.alert("Please connect to Metamask.")
        }
        // Modern dapp browsers...
        if (window.ethereum) {
          window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum)
          try {
            // Request account access if needed
            await ethereum.enable()
            // Acccounts now exposed
            web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */})
          } catch (error) {
            // User denied account access...
          }
        }
        // Legacy dapp browsers...
        else if (window.web3) {
          App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider
          window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
          // Acccounts always exposed
          web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */})
        }
        // Non-dapp browsers...
        else {
          console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!')
        }
    },

    loadAccount: async() => {
        App.account= web3.eth.accounts[0];
        console.log(App.account)

    },

    loadContract: async() => {
        const todoList = $.getJSON('TodoList.json');//Getting the smart contract json file
        //To do operations with our contract using truffle we need to do this
        App.contracts.TodoList = TruffleContract(todoList);
        App.contracts.TodoList.setProvider(App.web3Provider);//Also need to set the provider of web3
        //Creating a (deployed)contract instance from the actual blockchain of type App.
        //Check that the same variable 'todoList' is used to get the json file too

        App.todoList = App.contracts.TodoList.deployed();// <<<<-------- Here is the error I guess                 
    },
    render: async() => {
        //To Prevent double render
        if(App.loading){
            return
        }
        //Update app loading state
        App.setLoading(true);

        //Then render account
        $('#account').html(App.account)

        //Then update loading state
        App.setLoading(false);
    },
    setLoading:(status)=> {
        App.loading=status;
        const loader=$('#loader');
        const content=$('#content');

        if(status){
            loader.show()
            content.hide()
        }else{
            loader.hide()
            content.show()
        }

    },       
}
$(()=>{
    $(window).load(()=>{
        App.load()
    })
})
```

I have mentioned with <<<---- comment where the error occurs exactly
I'm newly learning blockchain from [this tutorial](http://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/blockchain-app-tutorial). Please help me out.Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the error. The error wasn't for any port or any network-artifact mismatch.Instead the contract json file wasn't loaded by the time we are trying to deploy it.

```
const todoList =await $.getJSON('TodoList.json'); //I added the await keyword and it worked fine.
```

I learnt an important lesson that everything in the blockchain is asynchronous. So we need to write all programs either using **promises** or using keywords like **async(),await**

Comment: You can accept your own answer. Accepting the correct answers is a good practice in SE sites.